# Turn on vibration on Android by terminal command

Tags: android, terminal, led, vibration

Since long I am modifying Android kernels, but now I am stuck to find prompt while starting the Android. I am adding recovery inside the kernel image. For this there will be a prompt like vibration, LED or flash light for entering the recovery as there is recovery for Sony Xperia devices.
I have now migrated to LG mobile. But here I can not find vibration trigger as I used before.

```
echo 200 > /sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/enable
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/red
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/green
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/blue
```

None of above mentioned trigger is available. Can anybody help me out that how can I run vibrator or flashlight for prompt by terminal command.
I am using LG V30 with Android Oreo and kernel version is 4.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/enable` exists at least on Qualcomm devices which have vibrator a part of PMIC, connected to SoC via SPMI bus. Timed-output was a class driver (vibrator appeared as a virtual device) in staging tree available up to Android kernel 3.18. On later devices AOSP treats vibrator as an LED module and vibrator HAL uses hardware/vendor specific kernel interfaces in `/sys/class/leds/vibrator/`. On such a device you can do:

```
~# echo -n 200 >/sys/class/leds/vibrator/duration
~# echo -n 1 >/sys/class/leds/vibrator/activate
```

References: [1](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r0.1/drivers/platform/msm/Kconfig#122), [2](http://pyeh.github.io/blog/2014/12/22/android-vibrator-on-msm8909-platform/), [3](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/661716/), [4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/61701df363310a5cbd95e3e1638baa9526e42c9b), [5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/27b2c1e678468d5001f1540c78ada9ba2d1e236e)

In order to make LEDs blink do:

```
~# echo -n 1 >/sys/class/leds/red/blink
~# echo -n 1 >/sys/class/leds/green/blink
~# echo -n 1 >/sys/class/leds/blue/blink
```